# Function with multiple parameters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I just received this test

```
function darling(w) {
/**
 * your code here
 */
}

/**
 * test functions, those in comment are expected returned value
 */
var demoIsWorking = demo();
var absolutely = darling('w')('i')('l')('l')['y']['o']['u'].m.a.r.r.y('m').e['?'];
var definitely = darling('w')('o')('u')('l')('d')['y']['o']['u'].m.a.r.r.y('m').e['?'];
var rUKidding = darling('w')('i')('l')('l')['y']['o']['u'].m.a.r.r.y('h').im['?'];
var yNot = darling('w')('o')('u')('l')('d')['y']['o']['u'].m.a.r.r.y('h').im['?'];
```

As you can see from the code when the program call a function darling, it's has many different parameters with different () and  []. It's really make me confuse. Can someone explain for me why the function is possible to have many parameters and also many bracket.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Yeah, I also need some explain. I know that () is for callable object and [] is for object literal, but I didn't see that two bracket come along together before.

Comment: That function is not called with multiple parameters (`(...)`). What's going on there is calling functions that retunr functions and so on. The `[...]` in turn is object key referencing `var obj = {"a": 1}; obj["a"] // => 1`. [About currying.](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/www_svendtofte_com/code/curried_javascript/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function can return anything, for example an object or another function. For example:

```
function matchesYou() {
  return { y: { o: { u: true } } };
}
```

Makes the following possible:

```
matchesYou().y.o.u;
```

Which you can also write as:

```
matchesYou()['y']['o']['u'];
```

Or any combination of both.

For round parentheses, it's even simpler:

```
function darling(w) {
  return function(iOrU) {
    return function(lOrU) {
      return function(l) {
        return true;
      };
    };
  };
}
```

You can call that like this:

```
darling('w')('i')('l')('l');
```

Or like this, it doesn't matter:

```
darling()()()();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is only one argument being passed at most.

What it's doing is it's actually doing chaining different functions by having a function return another.

```
function someFunction(w) {
  switch(w): {
    case 'a':
      return function() { ... }
    case 'b':
      return function() { ... }
  }
}
```

calling `someFunction` may return a completely different function depending on the argument passed.

Somewhere within those functions, it returns an array within an array

```
[
  ['a','b','c'],
  ['a','b','c'],
  ['a','b','c'],
];
```

Some of which containing objects

```
[{a:'1',b:'2' ....}], 'b']
```